# SQL Server credential doesn't work from Orange

Tags: orange

I am trying to have a SQL Table widget in my Orange canvas, which is connected to SQL Server. I have installed `pymssql`, and in the SQL Table dialog, I do get an option to connect to SQL Server.

However, after entering the credentials, I get the following error

> (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (DESKTOP-RABJ6QO\MIKA_SQLEXPRESS)\n')

How can I fix it?

Here is a screenshot of the dialog:

[image]